# Step response of critically damped PID controlled system

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, pid-controller, step-response, damping-factor

I thought that by definition: critically damped 2nd order system (ζ=1) does not have overshoot.

**Is the above assumption wrong?**

It might be on the verge of oscillation, but, it shouldn't oscillate.

However, I'm trying to control a 1st order system (using PID, therefore system become 2nd order) and have been very carefully setting the kp, ki, kd gains such that ζ=1.

I'm 100% sure that I have set kp, ki, and kd such that ζ=1, but I still get a very high overshoot to a step response.

My method is to set the system's ode into the form:
$$
Q\ddot{x}+2ζω_n\dot{x}+ω_n^2x=ω_n^2r
$$
which is also in the form:
$$
Q\ddot{x}+a\dot{x}+bx=br
$$
where r is the step input.
By letting ζ=1, therefore knowing:
$$
a^2 = 4bQ\ \Longleftarrow\ \left(Eq.1\right)
$$
I can set the Kp, Ki, and Kd such that Eq.1 always hold.

**Is this method incorrect? Is there other linearly independent equation(s) that governs critically damped system?**

Edit:

I have realize it is the zeros in the closed-loop-transfer-function (cltf) that is causing the overshoot. But I don't even know how the zeros should exist, considering the derivative of r is 0. (in the case when r is constant).

Note that the cltf numerator that I thought it should be when r is constant is:
$$
K_{i}
$$
vs the actual cltf numerator:
$$
K_{d}s^2 + K_{p}s + K_{i}
$$

**This brings out 2 additional questions: 1. Why is the cltf include zeros, and not simply just Ki? 2. Beside pre-filter, what can be done to the controller so that the system is critically damped?**

Comment: I know that I have set the Kp Ki Kd gains correctly because if I set up a transfer function of the ode with the gains substituted numerically, I get a critically damped response. However when I set up the transfer function of the original first order system inputted by PID control with the same kp ki kd gains, i get an overshoot. Why is this? How can I prevent this overshoot?

Comment: If the CLTF has a 2nd order denominator with \$\zeta=1\$, then it’s the zero that’s causing the overshoot.

Comment: Try to show both transfer functions, then deduce the overall t.f. and its inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: What are you calling a high overshoot? 100%? 15%? 1%?

Comment: For those of you wondering, @Chu is correct. It is the zero that causing the overshoot. This is proven, when I modified the CLTF to have no zero, it didnt have any overshoot. However, I'm still confused as to how is there a zero when the derivative of r is 0? An explanation on this would be great.

Comment: @user_1818839, its 20% overshoot

Comment: Also, I know that this problem can be eliminated using a pre-filter. But I really don't want to do that. Because, that is like solving a problem that should not have exist in the first place. An alternative to what controller should be and/or explanation to why there is a zeros even if derivative of r is 0 would be great.

Comment: A zero includes a proportional gain and a differentiator. The initial gradient of a step response is usually positive, so the differentiator adds value to the response; and sometimes the addition is sufficient to nudge the response over the unity gain line.

Comment: Are you using a digital computer? The zero-order hold has the Laplace Transform
(1 - e^(-T*s))/s and as all digitizing introduces non-minimum phase or right-hand plane zero that may cause overshoot. If you give me the Laplace transfer function I can evaluate it.